# Do features in Sci-kit learn have to be the same length

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have several features take from PCAP files these are network flow features

However the problem I have is that the features are not the same length

What I mean is for example here is a sample of my dataframe

```
TotBytes Dur            Afr                     DNS_Interval NTP_interval

250 0.030967    8073.110084929118   300.0        301.0
262 0.113429    2309.8149503213463  1.0      300.0
1960    0.062134    31544.725914957988  300.0        52.0
379 0.020444    18538.446487967132  10.0         300.0
1389    0.154713        8977.913943883192   40.0         1.0
```

End of the dataframe

```
TotBytes    Dur Afr               DNS_interval   NTP_interval 
262 0.099459    2634.25129953046    0.0      0.0
250 0.029093    8593.132368611006   0.0          0.0
250 0.024784    10087.153001936733  0.0      0.0
250 0.035297    7082.75490834915    0.0      0.0
262 0.112134        2336.46943              0.0          0.0
250 0.024445    10227.04029453876   0.0      0.0
```

As you can see the features DNS_interval and NTP_interval are not the same length as the other 3 features (TotBytes, Dur and Afr)

I am using Random Forest as the classifier. Does the features need to be the same length and if so what shall i do?

Do i fill in the missing figures with the mean? that a lot of zeros? if I did it seems to fill the same mean figure down the whole column where all the zeros are

Comment: Except for TotBytes, all your features look like ordinary floats to me. What do you exactly mean by "(not) the same length"? Additionally, have you actually tried training the classfier?

Answer (score 2):

The features need to be of the same length i.e. You should have no missing values in the dataset. Some models handle missing values internally but it's better to handle those.

There are a number of options that you have. Let's list each one of them.

**1.** In case the **number of missing values in a column is very less** compared to the size of DataFrame, you can drop the entire rows containing missing values.

```
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

This drops every row with any missing value. Make sure to check the size before and after dropping to ensure no substantial loss of data.

**2.** In case there are **very few values in a column** of a DataFrame, you can drop that entire feature/column.

```
df.drop(feature_list_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**3.** When **number of missing values are comparable to values present**.

There are various techniques to fill missing values and every technique is good at it's own place. You just need to find out which one is better for your dataset.

a. Fill with mean

```
df.feature.fillna(df.feature.mean(), inplace=True)
```

b. Fill with mode (In case one value dominates or is categorical)

```
df.feature.fillna(df.feature.mode()[0], inplace=True)
```

c. Make a model to predict that missing column value 
   (Tough to implement and time overhead but the best method

**4.** When nothing works out, just fill the missing values with some negative value like `-99`. Maybe the model figures out some sense from the fact that these values were missing.

Comment: Thanks...I have tried solution 1 already I did not have many features left...solution 2 - I definitely need the feature.... I have already tried solution 3 but I have ahave a lot of missing values...also when i use the mean or mode it seems to just fill the entire empty column with the same number

Comment: I am glad you have suggested these at least I know I have tried a few things

Comment: Just one more suggestion. you can try filling all missing values with some negative value like -99. The model might try to make sense and conclude from the fact that those were the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems fine. All the values are floats (except TotBytes). 
If you meant the precision of floating point by "length of features", it shouldn't matter with the classifier.

Comment: When I mean length I mean the length of the dataframe and 2 of the columns are not the same length...There are a lot of zeros at the end of the 2 columns